# Implementing remove chips inside an Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material table in which I've defined one column as an array of string values. I'm able to display these values as chips. However, I'd like to display these as removable chips. How can I do that?

Attaching [Stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-chips-array) for reference

I went through the [example](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview) on the Angular Material website. However, when I tried to implement it with my example, I ran into errors. The remove() function mentioned is implemented for an array of strings too but I couldn't figure out how to use it when the array exists inside the table.

```
remove(fruit: Fruit): void {
const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);

if (index >= 0) {
  this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you read over Angular Material documentation? There's an example of how to use removable chips here: https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview#chip-input

Comment: I did try to implement using that however I ran into errors. Specifically, I couldn't figure out how to implement the remove function. I'll update that.